# JPlayer Event - IOS Issue

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jplayer

I made a custom player using the JPlayer and I seem to have ran into an issue.  So I have an automated JQuery function that will look to see if something is clicked, it will than redirect to a correct page and auto play the song associated with it.  Now that works great, except when trying to use it on my IPhone, nothing happens(Chrome, Safari).  But if I click the play button the player will start playing.

Here is the function:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ 

        var songToPlay = $("input.songDirected").val();
        if(songToPlay == "falling-in-love")
        {
            //replace discription in select a song
            $("#openSongs").text("Falling In Love");

            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "mysite/wp-content/uploads/music/FallingInLoveMSTR31113_02.mp3"    
            });
            $('.jp-play').trigger('click');
        }
}, 1000);
```

Here is an example of what happens.  So this itself is placed within a function that will check for a value, if true; this executes.  Now so it will check to see what name of song is and associate the song given with the appropriate mp3, and trigger a click.  My issue is that, when clicking; nothing happens on it seems to be only the IPhone.

Please let me know suggestions or you're ideas?

David